# QT error code -529697949 while allocating memory

Tags: c++, qt, mingw

I'm using Qt 5.11 with Qt Creator 4.7.1 and I'm developing on Windows 10.

When I create a lot of windows that contains charts, the program crashes. I suppose that's because it doesn't have enough memory, but I'm not sure. The error is always shown when I create something - that means when I allocate more memory.

I have a `QMdiArea` and a toolbar with some `QToolButton`s. When I click a `QToolButton`, I create a `QMdiSubWindow` that contains some information like charts, tables and so on. I have seen that the problem can appear also when I resize a `QMdiSubWindow`: When I resize a `QMdiSubWindow` I allocate more memory, watching the resources of the PC.

In debugging mode I get this error:
-1: error: An exception was triggered: 
Exception at 0x4d47f50, code: 0xc000041d: , flags=0x0.

```
0x4d47f4e  <+0x00f6>        8b 30                    mov    (%eax),%esi
0x4d47f50  <+0x00f8>        89 31                    mov    %esi,(%ecx)
        213 [1] in painting\qmemrotate.cpp
```

The error I see in the application output pane is:
.../myapp exited with code -529697949

I tried to search this code on the net but I didn't find something useful about this error.

I'd like at least to understand if it's a real problem of insufficient memory or not.

Comment: You need to provide far more information for us to help you.

Comment: I have edited the message. Tell me if you need more information and specially what you need to know.

Comment: Run the application under debugger (press F5), then copy-paste the call stack into your question, as well as the code around the line where it crashed.

Comment: Great. What’s the call stack? We need a text copy-paste of that. But thus far it does look like you’re leaking memory: that’s how using progressively more memory without freeing it is called.

Comment: @KubaOber Thanks a lot for the answer. yeah that's what I was expecting. But I have to allocate more memory if I had to put a new object on my window with a lot of information. There is a way to say to the compiler that it needs more memory?